# How can I get the platform in Android 4.0 / Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Ice Cream Sandwich was announced just a few hours ago, and I've been playing around with the SDK for a few hours. Ice Cream Sandwich is special because it runs on both phones and tablets. One of the features I can't seem to find is a method that tells you if the OS is being run on a phone or a tablet device.

This would be extremely useful, as you may have to design things differently for phones because of the smaller screen size.

There's a new method in `Build` called `getRadioVersion()`, which returns the radio firmware version and null if the radio is not currently on. This is the closest I've been to finding what I'm looking for.

Comment: Isn't information about the screen size much *more* important than the rather arbitrary "phone"/"tablet" distinction? Some tablets are getting smaller, some phones are getting bigger. Also, many tablets *do* have radios, so that's not a reliable indicator either.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best way to do it. I suppose I could just use the DPI then?

Comment: DPI or you can make different layouts and add different layouts to different layout folders...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no "isTablet()" function anywhere in the Android Framework, or anything like that.  Really what you want to do is define different layouts for different screen sizes - Dianne Hackborn has a great post on how to do this called [New Tools for Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html), I'd recommend starting there.

By way of example of what's covered in that post, you can define a layout to be used for all screens with a width larger than 600dp by defining your layout in:

```
res/layout-sw600dp/someLayout.xml
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll keep it in mind for when I receive the Galaxy Nexus!

Comment: It's probably worth repeating the guidelines on how the "smallest width dp" numbers correspond with device classes:

320: a phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600: a 7” tablet (600x1024).
720: a 10” tablet (720x1280, 800x1280, etc).

Comment: @TrevorJohns How about the new Galaxy Nexus? It's using a 1280 x 720 screen but it's only 4.65 inches large.

Comment: @Michell Bak: The Galaxy Nexus is a normal/xhdpi screen. The system-reported screen dimensions are 720x1184, with a density scaling factor of 2.0. That would give it a smallest width of 360dp.